# PDO and Fetching results (String Conversion)

Tags: php, pdo

Currently having an issue with PDO im new to it also (which doesn't help)

this is the current segment of my code

```
> try{
$sql  = $conn->prepare(" SELECT Channel_Location FROM channels)
ORDER BY RAND()
limit 5");
$sql->execute(array(':Location' => ''));
$row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn =  null;
```

I'm basically trying to connect to the database and pull 5 random results from the table `Channel_Location` but i'm receiving a error Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string and i was wondering how i'd solve this by putting the 5 results it returns in to an array?

Comment: You have to remove parenthesis after `channels` in query; in the query there are not `:Location` to bind, you can't echo `$sql` because it is an object, not a string: simply echo `$e->getMessage`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
try {
    $sql = $conn->query("SELECT Channel_Location FROM channels ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

foreach($sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $c) {
    echo "$c <br>";
}
```

Will retrieve the information you want and display them on your page with a new line between each (:

Your request were incorrect and you did not had to put `prepare` / `execute` since you were not using any parameter, a simple `query`is enough here.

Comment: Its returning that `$sql` is undefined and there no database selected yet ive checked my include `database.php` and all is correct

Comment: Show use the code in database.php file

Comment: Added in to original thread

Comment: Where are you instanciating the $conn object?

Comment: `$conn = new PDO("mysql:'host='$servername . 'dbname='$dbname", $username, $password);`

Comment: Added full script to original thread

Answer (score 1):

```
   try{    
    $sql  = $conn->prepare("SELECT Channel_Location FROM channels ORDER BY RAND()
    limit 5");
    $sql->execute();
    $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
        echo $e->getMessage();
   }
   $conn =  null;
```